# how to add some string to all array item?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array like below

```
(0) = "apple"
(1) = "orange"
```

How can I add some string to all item in array? like apple become 'apple', orange become 'orange'

Edited

```
 Private Sub test()
        Dim txtReader As TextReader = New StreamReader("data.csv")
        Dim parser = New CsvParser(txtReader)
        Dim str As String = ""

        'Ignore first line
        parser.Read()

        While True
            Dim row = parser.Read()
            If row Is Nothing Then
                Exit While
            End If

            str &= $"({String.Join(",", row)}),"
        End While

        str_record = str.TrimEnd(",")
 End Sub

Private Sub Model_Insert()
    Dim data As String = ""
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO main_item(item_code,item_name,item_desc,item_unitprice,item_barcode,dept_id,cat_id,gst_id,set_item,active)" &
                          "VALUES " & str_record & ""

    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Im trying to create a string and use it in INSERT INTO

Comment: Can you try be clearer because it doesn't make much sense arrays normally work like this:  `Dim Fruit() As String = {"apple","orange","..."}`

Comment: Now you have modifed your question completely. Where is the array? Why dont you post the real issue you have in the first place?

Comment: Please,don't do that. Use parametrized queries, don't use string concatenation

Comment: @TimSchmelter row is the array

Comment: @TimSchmelter I use csvhelper library to read my csv file, parser.Read will return array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `For`-loop:

```
Dim array = {"apple", "orange"}
For i As Int32 = 0 To array.Length - 1
    array(i) = $"'{array(i)}'"
Next
```

If you can't use string interpolation yet, use `String.Format` (or string concatenation):

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To array.Length - 1
    array(i) = String.Format("'{0}'", array(i))
Next
```

Comment: is it possible to join  str &= $"({String.Join(",", array)})," with your second solution so I don't have to use for loop?

Comment: @vbnewbie: no, but why don't you want to use a for-loop? I thought you need to modify all strings in the array. Or you want a single string as result?

Comment: @vbnewbie: i have shown you an example how to use sql parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind recreating the array, you could use Linq `Select`:

```
Dim testarray As String() = New String() {"orange", "apple"}
testarray = testarray.Select(Function(x) String.Format("'{0}'", x)).ToArray()
```